# Grails pagination tag error

Tags: grails, groovy

i have this error when i click on the pagination button:
*Error processing GroovyPageView: Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total] at /home/user1/workspace/adm-appserver-manager/grails-app/views/emailNotification/status.gsp:59*

and my code is: 
in gsp:

```
<div class="paginateButtons">  
           <g:paginate total="${emailNotificationInstanceTotal}" />  

</div>
```

in controller:

```
def status = {
    [
        emailNotificationInstanceList:EmailNotification.findAllByStatus(EmailNotification.Status.Sent, params ),
        emailNotificationInstanceTotal:EmailNotification.countByStatus(EmailNotification.Status.Sent)  
    ]
}
```

i mention total attribute but i don't know why this error appear

Comment: Could you please paste all of your controller code ?

Comment: def status = {    [ emailNotificationInstanceList: EmailNotification.findAllByStatus(EmailNotification.Status.Sent, params ), emailNotificationInstanceTotal: EmailNotification.countByStatus(EmailNotification.Status.Sent)]}

Comment: this is the code in the controller i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your controller is returning this parameter in your return or render.  You should also add a default value in your controller or view, in case the source call fails.

```
<g:paginate total="${emailNotificationInstanceTotal?:0}" />
```

Or

```
emailNotificationInstanceTotal: EmailNotification.countByStatus(EmailNotification.Status.Sent)?:0
```

Comment: i try your answer, this answer avoid the error only, that the error doesn't appear, but it's result is wrong, since when i click on second pagination button a list appears empty, while the list still has record. Do you have another answer, if you please?!..

Comment: it sounds like your second call to the controller for the next page of results is not passing in the max or offset params, or your controller is not handling them properly to get the right resultset back to the view.  Add a println to your controller action and see if those params are making it back to the action.

Comment: i Add a println to my controller action, those params are making it back to the action

Comment: What was the value of offset and max params?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the emailNotificationInstanceTotal is null so you need to verify the value that is being sent from the controller or when this variable is being defined to make sure it is not null and has an int value that is 0 or higher.

Comment: emailNotificationInstanceTotal has a value equal to 26, i try to write in gsp code <h1> ${emailNotificationInstanceTotal}</h1>, and when i run my application number 26 appears that is number of records in database.

Comment: That is really strange, I have gotten this error only when the total value is null or not defined at all.

Comment: i know that, this error does not appear if total value > 0, but it is the first time i have this error with total value > 0, i don't know how i will solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try re-generating the controller. In my case, I had changed the domain class name once, but I havent re-generated the controller that caused me this error

Answer (score 0):

The grailsPaginationTag is basically used to handle the pagination for list that you render on a particular web page.

Here at Oodles Technologies, we work extensively with Grails Development.

For this plugins Just add one line in the config.groovy file .

**compile ":remote-pagination:0.4.8"**

Remote pagination plugins provides us tage for pagination using ajax without page loading. It provides us many tag for pagination for list of object you needed.

For Example:

```
public class Person{
   String name
   long id
   }
```

On controller

```
public class PersonController{

   def list{
   [list:Person.list()]
   }

   def filterPersonList{
   render('listTemplate',model:[count:Person.list().size(),list:Person.list()])
   }
   }
```

Now on your _listTemplate gsp

Action: name of the link to be used in the pagination

Total: size of the list

update : id of the div/span which contain the template

max: fetch max list

params:pass your own params

maxsteps: The number of step displayed for the pagination

This might help in getting rid of the error.

Hope it helps.