# grails exception: Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]

Tags: exception, grails

I've the following method in my controller, that is used to list the Patient entities:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)


    def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
    if(roles == 'ROLE_USER')
    {
        [patientInstanceList: Patient.findAllBySecUser(springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()), patientInstanceTotal: Patient.count()]
    }
    else if(roles == 'ROLE_ADMIN' || roles == 'ROLE_MANAGER')
    {
        [patientInstanceList: Patient.list(params), patientInstanceTotal: Patient.count()]
    }
}
```

If I perform this method I have the exception

```
Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]
```

But, if I use the following

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [patientInstanceList: Patient.list(params), patientInstanceTotal: Patient.count()]
    }
}
```

Everything works well. I see all the instances of Patient created. I only want that, based on role of user logged in, I can see a part of all the entities created. Why does this exception is raised?

I've found here [Grails pagination tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944839/grails-pagination-tag-error) something similar, but no good answer was given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can ommit the return in a if statement. Another detail is that you're filtering your domain records in the `ROLE_USER`, but counting the total independent of this filter.

You can try this approach:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

    def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()

    def model

    //I think roles is a list so your equals will not work...
    def admin = roles.find { it.authority == 'ROLE_ADMIN' || it.authority == 'ROLE_MANAGER' }
    if(admin) {
       model = [patientInstanceList: Patient.list(params), patientInstanceTotal: Patient.count()]
    } else {
      //createCriteria().list(params) will paginate...  
      def patientInstanceList = Patient.createCriteria().list(params) {
        eq('secUser', springSecurityService.currentUser)
      }
      //totalCount will trigger a query without the limit, but applying your filter
      model = [patientInstanceTotal: patientInstanceList.totalCount, patientInstanceList: patientInstanceList]
    }

    //and finally we return the model
    //return model
    //just to show that the return is optional

    model

}
```

Comment: the method was autogenerated without any return statement but I will try your code...

Comment: @FrancescoDS In Groovy you can ommit the `return`. It will return whet you have in your last line of the method, so there's a hidden return in the generated code :-)